# Using VB to convert Excel rows to a file

Tags: excel, vbscript, rows

A little inexperienced with VB, so I hope somebody can help with what feels like a simple problem!

Essentially, I need to generate a text file (with .exp extension) for each row of an Excel spreadsheet. However, the number of columns and rows is unknown in advance, and the format needs to be fairly specific. For example, given the following Excel format:

```
Col1 | Col2
1    | 2
8    | 9
17   | 46
```

I'd expect 3 files produced. The first file would read as follows:

```
Col1 1
Col2 2
```

The second:

```
Col1 8
Col2 9
```

The third:

```
Col1 17
Col2 46
```

Is there a simple way to do this using VB?

Comment: you have tags `vb.net` and `script` which are exclusive IMHO. Is this a VB.NET program or a VBA script?

Comment: @w0lf It'd be a Windows Script File ideally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I played with VBA but something like this should work: -

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim stream As TextStream
Dim iLoop As Integer
iLoop = 1
While Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & iLoop) <> ""
    Set stream = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Row" & iLoop & ".txt", True)
    stream.WriteLine "Col1 " & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & iLoop)
    stream.WriteLine "Col2 " & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & iLoop)
    stream.Close
    iLoop = iLoop + 1
Wend
```

May need some tweaking, I haven't tested this but this is the basic idea.

Comment: Looks promising, but throws an error on line 6, character 10 with the Excel test file I have (formatted the same as my example).

Comment: See the edit, and make sure you reference the Microsoft Scripting Runtime by going to Tools -> References -> 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime'

Comment: This is an example, of course, it assumes that your first row starts at row 1. If your data starts at row 5, then change the initial value of iLoop to 5

Comment: Works a charm, thanks :) Any idea how I'd adjust it to so that it works with a variable number of columns? So, there may be more than just Col1 and Col2, so I'd need a while loop to check how many there were. Sorry - completely hopeless at VBA! Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you want to add more columns, you would just need to add another 'stream.WriteLine "Col2 " & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & iLoop)'. That would then write another line for Column C

Comment: How about a sheet with ~1000 columns? :)

Comment: You could create a loop inside the original loop that loops from 1 to N using 'Cells' instead of range. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I never using Excel, nor yet have a copy to test any code, so bear with me.

A base idea for VBScript (stand-alone .vbs file)...

```
'connect to Excel
Set XLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
XLApp.Visible = True

'open the file
XLApp.DisplayAlerts = False
Set XLBook = XLApp.WorkBooks.Open("c:\path_to\my.xls")
XLApp.DisplayAlerts = True

'if you know the Worksheet name:
sSheetName = "MySheetName"
Set XLSheet = XLBook.Sheets.Item(sSheetName)

'else use index:
Set XLSheet = XLBook.Worksheets(1)

'or if you want to process all sheets:
For Iter = 1 To XLBook.Worksheets.Count
    Set XLSheet = XLBook.Worksheets(Iter)
    ...
Next

'you can use XLSheet.Columns.Count to iterate
'or if the columns names are known:
Set Col1 = XLSheet.Columns("Col1")
Set Col2 = XLSheet.Columns("Col2")

'or get Range:
Set Range = XLSheet.Columns("Col1:Col2")
'same as above:
Set Range = XLSheet.Range("Col1:Col2")

'vbs FileSystemObject:
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

iLoop  = 1 'to enumerate file names
intRow = 2 '?... not sure about this

Do While Range.Cells(intRow,1).Value <> ""
    Set stream = fso.CreateTextFile("Row" & iLoop & ".exp", True)
        stream.WriteLine "Col1 " & Range.Cells(intRow, 1).Value
        stream.WriteLine "Col2 " & Range.Cells(intRow, 2).Value
    stream.Close
    iLoop = iLoop + 1
    intRow = intRow + 1
Loop

'XLBook.Save
XLBook.Close
XLApp.Quit

Set stream = Nothing
Set fso    = Nothing
Set Range  = Nothing
Set XLSheet = Nothing
Set XLBook  = Nothing
Set XLApp   = Nothing
```